# How do I pass input value to function parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to pass input field value to function parameter, reverse string and print it out.

I have figured out how to print input field text but I have not a clue how to pass it through a function.

```
<form>
  <p>Input your text here:</p>
  <input type="text" id="inputFieldValue" />
  <input type="button" id="buttonClick" value="Click me!">
</form>

<span id="resultHere"></span>
```

/* this one works but it just prints input field text*/

```
$('#buttonClick').click(function() { 
    print = $('#inputFieldValue').val();
    $('#resultHere').text(print);
});
```

/*I don't know how to make this work: */

```
someText = $('#inputFieldValue').val();

$('#buttonClick').click(function reverseMe(print) {
    var printMe = print.split('').reverse().join('');
    $('#resultHere').text(printMe);
});
reverseMe(someText);
```

I just want it to reverse string and print into HTML.

Example input: 'Hello, World!'
Output: '!dlroW ,olleH'

I want to use JS or Jquery for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to first create a function that reverse a `string` and returns it, that will be his only purpose. Then use it inside the `click` event handler before displaying the `text`, like this:

```js
$('#buttonClick').click(function()
{
    let print = $('#inputFieldValue').val();
    $('#resultHere').text(reverseStr(print));
});

const reverseStr = (inputStr) => inputStr.split("").reverse().join("");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <p>Input your text here:</p>
  <input type="text" id="inputFieldValue" />
  <input type="button" id="buttonClick" value="Click me!">
</form>

<span id="resultHere"></span>
```

Why not to include the logic that also shows the text in the `span` element inside the `reverseStr` method? Because you will lose reusability of that method.

Note also, [function arrow expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) are [not fully supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Browser_compatibility). So you may consider using a standard function declaration instead.

```
function reverseStr(inputStr)
{
    return inputStr.split("").reverse().join("");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wanted to do something simple as I am just beginner. Your method of tacking it seems interesting as well and it works too. Thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that this will not work for Internet Explorer, as IE does not support arrow functions.  It will work for MS Edge though.  @BlackC4t

Comment: @Taplar Thanks for the feedback, I'm going to add an alternative for that.

Answer (score 3):

Try defining the function `reverseMe` outside the event handler, and declaring the variable `someText` inside the handler's function.

This should do it:

```
$('#buttonClick').click(function() {
  someText = $('#inputFieldValue').val();
  reverseMe(someText);
});

function reverseMe(print) {
    var printMe = print.split('').reverse().join('');
    $('#resultHere').text(printMe);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extract the method out of the event listener, and call it from the listener, passing in the value to reverse.

```
function reverseMe(print) {
    var printMe = print.split('').reverse().join('');
    $('#resultHere').text(printMe);
}

someText = $('#inputFieldValue').val();

$('#buttonClick').click(function(){
    reverseMe($('#inputFieldValue').val());
});

reverseMe(someText);
```

Comment: To add to this, the reason it happens is because you are trying to use reverseme as a callback function that is not seen outside it's own scope

Comment: It seems you are reversing the wrong string in `reverseMe(e.target.value);`?

Comment: @AnisR. revised.